# RegEx for finding copy constructors

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I was trying to find all occurences of my c# copy constructor-like constructors with the search window in visual studio using regex.

For example, I would like to find the following:

```
MyClass(MyClass other)
```

I used the following regex, but it did not give any results (it should):

```
(?<cn>\w)\(?<cn> \w\)
```

What do I do wrong please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answers, I could successfully build the right RegEx for Visual Studio:

```
(?<cpy>\b\w+\b)\s*\(\s*\k<cpy>\s+\w+\s*\)
```

Comment: this things has false positives for methods with the only parameter of type named identically to the method name

Answer (score 0):

`(public|static|private|internal|protected|protected\s+internal)\s+\w+\s*\(\s*\w+\s+\w+\s*(\s*,\s*\s*\w+\s+\w+\s*)*\)` find all ctors

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work in Visual Studio, but you can use first match for MyClass as \1 in the rest of regexp:

```
(\w+)\s*\(\1\s*\w+\)
```